# Scraping Data from a website

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, screen-scraping

Hi I have a website that I want to get data from I am able to scrape all the text from the site but what I want is a specific bit of data.
A sample website where I want to get the data from is
http://www.irishferries.com/ie-en/to-britain-from-ireland/

Firstly I'd have to select route and then get and select the month followed by the available days that the sailing is available and once that is selected the available times,

All I have at the moment is below

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1


Private Sub scrapeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles scrapeButton.Click

    If (Not linkURL.Text = Nothing) Then
        linkURL.Text = linkURL.Text.ToLower()
        If (linkURL.Text.StartsWith("https://") Or linkURL.Text.StartsWith("http://")) Then
            If (Not linkURL.Text.StartsWith("https://www.") And Not linkURL.Text.StartsWith("http://www.")) Then
                If Not (linkURL.Text.StartsWith("www.")) Then
                    If (linkURL.Text.StartsWith("http://")) Then
                        linkURL.Text = "http://www." & linkURL.Text.Substring(7, linkURL.Text.Length - 7)
                    Else
                        linkURL.Text = "https://www." & linkURL.Text.Substring(8, linkURL.Text.Length - 8)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        ElseIf (linkURL.Text.StartsWith("www.")) Then
            linkURL.Text = "http://" & linkURL.Text
        Else
            linkURL.Text = "http://www." & linkURL.Text
        End If
    End If

    Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(linkURL.Text)
    Dim res As HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse()
    Dim src As String = New StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()

    srcBox.Text = src
end sub
end class
```

I don't know how to interact with the website to select route and then pull the information from it, 
any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at that website, it appears to be doing ajax calls to retrieve the info you're looking for. If you run Fiddler or Chrome's network profiler, you can see it making the GET calls in the background. When you select a route, it makes an ajax call then uses the json data to populate the date and departure time select options.

So one possible way would be to recreate that initial ajax call and parse the json data returned to build the subsequent calls to get the rest of the data. Then you don't have to worry about interacting with the html page or its elements.

**EDIT**

Here's an example using one of the ajax calls. Call doGetRouteData. It has a class that represents the JSON object being returned. There's a problem though...the last line is throwing an error when it tries to deserialize the json data. I'm not sure why, maybe you can figure it out.

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

<DataContract()> _
Public Class RouteData
    Implements IExtensibleDataObject
    ' To implement the IExtensibleDataObject interface, you must also 
    ' implement the ExtensionData property. 
    Private extensionDataObjectValue As ExtensionDataObject

    Public Property ExtensionData() As ExtensionDataObject _
      Implements IExtensibleDataObject.ExtensionData
        Get
            Return extensionDataObjectValue
        End Get
        Set(value As ExtensionDataObject)
            extensionDataObjectValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember(Name:="Departure")> _
    Public Departure As String '{ get; set; } 
    <DataMember(Name:="Arrival")> _
    Public Arrival As String '{ get; set; } 
    <DataMember(Name:="SameDay")> _
    Public SameDay As Boolean '{ get; set; } 
    <DataMember(Name:="Route")> _
    Public Route As String '{ get; set; } 

End Class

Public Sub doGetRouteData()
    Dim webRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.irishferries.com/Service/BookingInformation.svc/SailingTimes/HHDDUB/2014-5-20?version=22")
    webRequest.Method = "GET"
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
    Dim responseReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    Dim responseData As String = responseReader.ReadToEnd()

    responseReader.Close()
    webRequest.GetResponse().Close()

    Dim ser As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(RouteData))
    Dim ByteConverter As New UnicodeEncoding()
    Dim newRouteData As New List(Of RouteData)
    Dim stream = New MemoryStream(ByteConverter.GetBytes(responseData))
    newRouteData = CType(ser.ReadObject(stream), List(Of RouteData)) '<= throws an error here, haven't figured out why

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Would you be able to show me some code that would recreate the first ajax call and get the json data returned? I've never worked with either of these before so I woudln't know where to start.

Comment: I updated my answer above. That should be enough to get you started.